# Can view orders/invoices after update to CE 1.9.2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, backend, ce-1.9.2.0

I just updated my site to latest Magento 1.9.2.0 and i am getting this while trying to view an order

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getFullCustomerName() in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php on line 2060
```

If i comment out this line... the field is blank and everything else works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getFullCustomerName()` was introduced in Magento 1.9.2, so it sounds like your Mage_Customer_Helper_Data class is from an older version.

The most likely explanation is an override in `app/code/local`, which is bad practice by the way, and can be avoided in almost all cases. If you need to modify a method, the cleaner solution is a class rewrite that only overrides this method.

A quick fix would be to check what you had changed in your overridden class (compare to the original version from Magento 1.9.1 or whatever version you copied it from), replace it with the original file from Magento 1.9.2 and re-apply your changes.

Comment: Yup that's what i thought because i made some overrides there in the past but was long time ago... I already made a quick look but i didn't find any. Let me recheck...

Comment: maybe is an override i made in /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php?

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Comment: Yup renamed and solved the problem... I made an override of this file in the past to solve a VAT Validation problem.. Let me see if with the new version validation is ok